# How to write rspec for method inside which other class object is instantiated

Tags: ruby, rspec, jruby, rspec-rails

I want to write rspec for class A's test method in ruby

```
class A
  def test
    b = B.new
    b.run!
  end
end

class B
  def run!
    return 1
  end
end
```

Can someone please tell how can I do this using mock

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
let(:a) { A.new }
let(:b_mock) { instance_double(B, run!: 'result') }

describe '#test'
  it 'instantiates B and calls #run!' do
    allow(B).to receive(:new).and_return(b_mock)

    a.test

    expect(b_mock).to have_received(:run!)
  end
end
```

Essentially you want to "spy" on the created instance, and check that it has received the method you expected.

You *could* also just test that `A#test` returns `1`, however, such a test is really verifying the behaviour of `B#run!`, meaning your tests are coupled.

Answer (score 0):

```
b = double(:b, run!: nil)
B.stub(new: b)

expect(b).to receive(:run!)

A.new.test
```